# Finding the last digit of $7^n$, $n\ge 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

I have noticed a cycle of 7,9,3,1. Meaning: $7^1\equiv 7\pmod {10}, 7^2\equiv 9\pmod {10}, 7^3\equiv 3\pmod {10},7^4\equiv 1\pmod {10}, 7^5\equiv 7\pmod {10}$ and so on. Therefore, if $n=4k+1$ the last digit is 7, If $n=4k+2$, the last digit is 9, If $n=4k+3$, the last digit is 3 and if $n=4k$, the last digit is 1. I don't really know how to get to a final, coherent answer. That is as far as I could. I guess I am required to present a specific function the outputs the exact last digit. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This seems fine to me. One thing I can think of that would improve it is to list your results in a more readable way, so instead of inside a paragraph of text, write it as
\begin{align}7^{4k} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}\\7^{4k+ 1} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}\\7^{4k+ 2} \equiv 9 \pmod{10}\\7^{4k + 3} \equiv 3 \pmod{10}\\\end{align}Of course, an explicit _proof_ that your cycle is _actually_ a cycle as in the answers below won't hurt either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have everything figured out.  For a proof, suppose that $n = 4k + \alpha$, where $\alpha < 4$.  Then
$$ 7^n = 7^{4k+\alpha} = 7^{4k} 7^{\alpha} = {7^4}^k 7^\alpha = 2401^k 7^\alpha \equiv 1^k 7^\alpha = 7^\alpha, \quad \hbox{ (mod 10)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Take $n=4m+k$ where $0\leq k\leq 3$, then
$$7^{4m+k}=7^{4m}\cdot 7^k=(7^4)^m\cdot 7^k\equiv 1^m 7^k \equiv 7^k (mod 10).$$

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for is something like this :
$$f(n) = \frac{2}{3} (n\%4-(n\%4)^3) + 1$$
it's a result I obtained by using 3rd degree linear regression, with the points $(0,1)$,$ (1,7)$,$ (2,9)$, and $ (3,3)$. 
Anaway, I'm pretty sure that nicer solutions exist, just haven't found them yet.

Comment: Call it non-standard... Since the function $n\mapsto 7^n\mod 10$ turns out to be $4$-periodic, you can actually find $\deg =3$ polynomial in $n\mod4$ interpolating it, I guess.